# Magento custom shipping module - Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore()

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

working with magento 1.9.0.1 I did my custom module like this [tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/15/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/)

I followed this tutorial step by step but in my production server doesn't work.

**In the cart on the frontend I get the error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping.php on line 424**

I've readed a lot of questions here without luck. Like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440890/fatal-error-with-custom-magento-shipping-module) I cleaned cache, disabled and enabled the compiler, I've compilated via terminal etc.. but the error still here.

Here the code:

**/app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Company_Module>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Shipping />
        </depends>
    </Company_Module>
</modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Company_Module>
        <module>0.0.1</module>
    </Company_Module>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <company_module>
            <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
        </company_module>
    </models>
</global>
<!-- Default configuration -->
<default>
    <carriers>
        <company_module>
            <active>1</active>
            <!--
                 This configuration should not be made visible
                 to the administrator, because it specifies
                 the model to be used for this carrier.
            -->
            <model>company_module/carrier</model>
            <!--
                The title as referenced in the carrier class
            -->
            <title>Transporte Test</title>

            <sort_order>10</sort_order>

            <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
        </company_module>
    </carriers>
</default>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<sections>
    <carriers translate="label" module="shipping">
        <groups>
            <company_module translate="label">
                <label>Transporte Test</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>

                    <active translate="label">
                        <label>Enabled</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </active>

                    <title translate="label">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </title>

                    <sort_order translate="label">
                        <label>Sort Order</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </sort_order>

                    <sallowspecific translate="label">
                        <label>Transporte aplicado a los siguientes paises</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </sallowspecific>

                    <specificcountry translate="label">
                        <label>Envio a países especificos</label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                    </specificcountry>
                </fields>
            </company_module>
        </groups>
    </carriers>
</sections>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/carrier.php**

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Model_Carrier extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    protected $_code = 'company_module';

public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

    /* @var $result Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result */

    $result->append($this->_getStandardShippingRate());


    return $result;
}

protected function _getStandardShippingRate()
{
    $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
    // @var $rate Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method

    $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
     //
     // getConfigData(config_key) returns the configuration value for the
     // carriers/[carrier_code]/[config_key]
     //
    $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $rate->setMethod('standand');
    $rate->setMethodTitle('Standard, de 5 a 10 días');

    $rate->setPrice(14000);
    $rate->setCost(0);

    return $rate;
}

public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return array(
        'standard' => 'Standard'
    );
}

public function isTrackingAvailable()
{
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: What happens with disabled compiler?

Comment: Clear and disabled via terminal and mydomain.com/checkout/cart --> blank page with this: Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping.php on line 424

Comment: When you disable you compiler magento shouldn't use folder includes/src. Maybe you have APC/Varnish or maybe you disable cache in another magento?

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm working on the correct magento it is installed in amazon ec2 with a basic ubuntu installation,without varnish etc... All actions I did was via terminal.

Comment: Check your includes/config.php all lines should begin from comment symbol '#'

Comment: I have this:##define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');

Comment: Now the error is not in /src now is this: Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php on line 424

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Your error is in method **getCarrierByCode**</s>

Try to put there `Mage::log($carrierCode, false, 'mylog.log', true);`

```
$obj = Mage::getModel($className);
```

<s>Your carrier code contains underscode, try to remove it. If it will not help - show the result of Mage::log</s>

**upd.1**
And remove underscore from model too

```
<model>company_module/carrier</model>
```

**upd.2**
I copy-pasted everything from your post with a bit difference.

```
/app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Carrier.php
```

File name Carrier.php (you used with all letters in lower case). And your module is working properly. I successfully placed the order.

Comment: I did this changes: 
Step1: In carrier.php in line 4 I've deleted the underscore: protected $_code = 'companymodule';
Step2:  in My config.xml I've modified the line <model>company_module/carrier</model>  for this line <model>companymodule/carrier</model>
I did something wrong?
I puted this in the method getCarrierByCode..> Mage::log(false, $carrierCode, 'mylog.log', true);Mage::log(false, 'test', 'mylog.log', true);  But the log file is empty.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Mage::log($carrierCode, false, 'mylog.log', true); If log still empty - check if its enabled system / configuration / developer / log settings / Enabled set to yes. As you know log is in var/log/mylog.log

Comment: 2015-04-07T15:12:06+00:00 EMERG (): flatrate
2015-04-07T15:12:06+00:00 EMERG (): freeshipping
2015-04-07T15:12:06+00:00 EMERG (): company_module
2015-04-07T15:17:28+00:00 EMERG (): flatrate
2015-04-07T15:17:28+00:00 EMERG (): freeshipping
2015-04-07T15:17:28+00:00 EMERG (): company_module   Still with underscore? I changed it in confing.xml and in carrier.php

Comment: Your code works properly! Read my upd2. above. 
I'm sorry that knocked you out of the way with underscore.

Comment: I can't believe that this f**king "c" was my nightmare. I've put Carrier.php and now it's working fine...  in localhost works fine "carrier.php" and "Carrier.php" but in the server only works "Carrier.php". Omg Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Glad to hear that everything is working well. When I create some simple module and it's not working I try to create it module again or do it using module creator. Good luck